# How to create files from specific lines of file avoiding blank lines?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to create files based on the first 10 lines of a file.

Here is what I have got so far:

```
var lines2 = File.ReadLines(fileName).Take(10);
foreach (string newFile in lines2)
{
    CreateiniFile(folder, newFile);
}
```

This is calling `CreateiniFile` which is here:

```
static void CreateiniFile(string directory, string name)
{
    string filename = String.Format("File_" + name + ".ini");
    string path = Path.Combine(directory, filename);
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Text");
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This creates the correct files if all 10 lines have data on, however if any of the lines are blank it creates a file `File_.ini`.

How can I stop it creating files based on a null return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want first 10 nonempty lines:

```
var lines2 = File
    .ReadLines(fileName)
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    .Take(10);
```

If you want at most 10 first nonempty lines:

```
var lines2 = File
    .ReadLines(fileName)
    .Take(10)
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line));
```